# Counterexamples in algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, field-theory, modules, big-list

I got the feeling that whenever a subject gets so sophisticated that Zorn's lemma is needed, a book of counterexamples in that subject would probably benefit researchers/ students a lot.

Zorn's lemma definitely appears a lot in abstract algebra, and I often find myself thinking about statements I can neither find a proof nor counterexamples. This is fun but sometimes it could be time consuming.

Therefore I wonder whether there is a book of counterexamples in algebra, or just a nice collection of them somewhere. Maybe algebra is too large a subject, so such a collection from sub-subject (field theory, modules, etc) is also welcome.

Thanks!

As mentioned in the comment, there is [a nice list](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29006/counterexamples-in-algebra) on M.O. However, that list is a little bit random. I am looking for something that might be more systematic if less instructional.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29006/counterexamples-in-algebra

Comment: Can you give us an idea what a "systematic" list of examples would look like?! I guess maybe you just mean "a list that fits the needs of your average algebra course." I say this because I don't think you are really asking us to systematize all false statements and their counterexamples that we are aware of...

Comment: The consensus on the MO question seemed to be that such a thing didn't exist.

Comment: So did you want counterexamples which involve Zorn's lemma, or...?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Not really. I do not really care about Zorn's lemma, but I think it is a sign of the degree of abstractness of a subject.

Comment: You can do a lot of interesting abstract algebra without invoking Zorn's lemma (or something equivalent like the axiom of choice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One such systematic collection of counter-examples may not exist now. I will just close this question with [one link from MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29006/counterexamples-in-algebra) given in the comments. It does contain many instructive examples/counter-examples but some of them are rather advanced and they are not arranged in a systematic way.

Answer (score 3):

If you do a search in Amazon for "consequences of the axiom of choice",
the first responses are:

Consequences of the Axiom of Choice (Mathematical Surveys and Monographs) by Paul Howard ($108.00)

The Axiom of Choice (Dover Books on Mathematics) by Thomas J. Jech ($11.05, also Kindle)

Zermelo's Axiom of Choice: Its Origins, Development, and Influence (Dover Books on Mathematics) by Gregory H. Moore ($14.44)