# Counterexamples in Group Theory and Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question

I am studying Group Theory from Basic Algebra(Nathan Jacobson) and Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze. The exercises in both the books are interesting. However when I try to solve question papers of grad school entrance exams, I am often confronted by Group Theory and Linear Algebra questions that require knowledge of counterexamples. I feel that the exercises from the above mentioned books do not help me much in solving such questions. Is there any book which deals with counterexamples in Algebra? I have come across such books for Analysis and Topology but not for algebra. Kindly help.

Answer (score 3):

This website has some useful content [Math Counterexamples](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/)

Comment: Thanks. Will check it out.

Comment: @tony https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334835/counterexamples-in-algebra

Comment: thanks for the suggestion